# Why MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY is used in DEX like Uniswap?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, liquidity-provider

1. What is the `MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY` value used for?
2. Why did they chose this numerical value?

`uint256 public constant MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY = 10**3;`

3. Why should it be burned? The `mint` function in the `UniswapV2Pair.sol` file has this code:

`_mint(address(0), MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY);`

Answer (score 6):

1. The answer is given in the [Uniswap v2 whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper.pdf):

> Uniswap v2 initially mints shares equal to the geometric mean of the
> amounts deposited [..] it is possible for the value of a liquidity
> pool share to grow over time, either by accumulating trading fees or
> through “donations” to the liquidity pool. In theory, this could
> result in a situation where the value of the minimum quantity of
> liquidity pool shares (1e-18 pool shares) is worth so much that it
> becomes infeasible for small liquidity providers to provide any
> liquidity. To mitigate this, Uniswap v2 burns the first 1e-15
> (0.000000000000001) pool shares that are minted (1000 times the
> minimum quantity of pool shares), sending them to the zero address
> instead of to the minter. This should be a negligible cost for almost
> any token pair.11 But it dramatically increases the cost of the above
> attack. In order to raise the value of a liquidity pool share to $100,
> the attacker would need to donate $100,000 to the pool, which would be
> permanently locked up as liquidity.

2. There are 18 decimals in the ERC20 token describing the Uniswap v2 pool shares. Therefore the number `10**3` given in the code above is equal to  1e-15 of a single LP token, as described in the whitepaper above. The value was selected to increase the cost of the attack by several (three) orders of magnitude while avoiding hurting the first liquidity provider too much.
3. To increase the cost of the attack, as described above.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding to the answer provided by @kfx with an example:

In the absence of preset burning, an attacker initializes a pool with 10e-18 weth and 10e-18 dai. This would mint 1LP token which also becomes the total supply. The attacker then transfers 100weth and 100dai to the pair contract and calls the sync function. Now 1LP token is worth 100weth + 100dai. For a new liquidity provider to provide liquidity to the pool, he must now atleast provide 100 eth and 100 dai making it difficult for small liquidity providers to join the pool.

When an initial amount of 1000LP tokens are burned, there will always be atleast 1000LP tokens. Hence if a donation of 100eth was made, that would represent the increase in the cumulative worth of atleast 1000LP tokens. This would increase the price of a single LP token by just 0.1 max. Hence an attacker would have to spend 1000x more the amount to perform the above attack.

Comment: good example, upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

### 0x1. Problem

When users decide to become a liquidity provider, they should deposit paired tokens in proportion to the exchange rate, that is:

[image]

Imagining an attacker who holds large sums of money wants to prevent anyone else from providing liquidity into ETH / USDT pool by depositing **a small amount** of ETH and **a large amount** of USDT, or vice versa, this changes the exchange rate to, let's say:

[image]

What does it mean? Well, it means whenever **you depoist 1 *wei* in ETH**, **you should also deposit the equivalent of 2 million USDT** into the liquidity pool.

Now the attacker is rewarded with LP tokens as a pool share, he could redeem the funds by burning the corresponding LP tokens:

[image]

How much is a LP token worth? If we denominate it in USDT, that is:

[image]

Suppose that there is only 1 LP token minted in the pool, then the unit price is:

[image]

In other words, **attackers can raise the price of LP token by increasing the amount of deposited token *x* or *y***. This is what the situation mentioned in the whitepaper:

> However, it is possible for the value of a liquidity pool share to grow over time, either by accumulating trading fees or through “donations” to the liquidity pool. In theory, this could result in a situation where the value of the minimum quantity of liquidity pool shares (1e-18 pool shares) is worth so much that it becomes infeasible for small liquidity providers to provide any liquidity.

In general, we can look at this problem from different perspectives:

- If you want to depoist 1 *wei* in ETH, you must also deposit 2 millions USDT.
- If you expect to acquire 1 pool share, you must deposit 2 millions USDT.

### 0x2. Solution

Attackers couldn't deposit arbitrary amount of token *x* or *y* by simply calling the `addLiquidity` function due to the restriction of the price ratio formula. Instead, attackers can accomplish the attack through following approaches:

- **Initialize a new liquidity pool**: anyone who creates a new liquidity pool can determine the initial ratio of the token pair by design.
- **Directly transfer token into an existing `UniswapV2Pair` contract**: that is, this is so called "donation" since you won't be getting any pool share.

In order to spare no effort to increase the price of the LP tokens, the attacker combines both approaches to manipulate the price:

1. Attacker **deposits 10,000 *wei* ETH and 10,000 *wei* NextGenUSDT** by creating a new liquidity pool, the pool also minted 10,000 LP token as a pool share:

[image]

2. Attacker then **signed a transaction to transfer 2 millions NextGenUSDT into the contract**, which is the liquidity pool.
3. With 10,000 *wei* ETH and 2 millions NextGenUSDT (we ignore the first 10,000 *wei* which deposited at the initial stage) within the pool, **now a single LP token is worth 200 dollars**:

[image]

4. The attacker can still withdraw all tokens including that of transfered directly into the pool, since he held 100% of shares.

To mitigate this situation, **Uniswap V2 reduces a small proportion of LP tokens, which is defined as `MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY = 1000`**, from the first user who initialized the liquidity pool.

As one LP token equals to 200 dollars, the attacker will totally loss of:

[image]

If the attacker transfers more tokens into the pool, **causing the price of a LP token hikes up to 300 dollars, the attacker now losses of $300,000 dollars.**

Getting back to the whitepaper, this is the consequence that author has described:

> To mitigate this, Uniswap v2 burns the first 1e-15 (0.000000000000001) pool shares that are minted (1000 times the minimum quantity of pool shares), sending them to the zero address instead of to the minter. This should be a negligible cost for almost any token pair. But it dramatically increases the cost of the above attack. In order to raise the value of a liquidity pool share to $100, the attacker would need to donate $100,000 to the pool, which would be permanently locked up as liquidity.

### 0x3. Answers

1. What is the `MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY` value used for?

   It is used for mitigate the situation where someone tries to make a large discrepancy in quantities between a trading pair.
2. Why did they chose this numerical value?

   Because every pool's founding father sustains losses, this should be a affordable price for a normal user.
3. Why should it be burned?

   The number of `MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY` minted to the zero address will never be burnt even though the liquidity provider withdrew all funds.

### 0x4. Conclusion

In my opinion, this scenario is unlikely to happen because it gives an opportunity to arbitrageurs that take advance of the price differences between various marketplaces. I hope this long story will help.